# Installing spacy_readability in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip, spacy

I am trying to use spacy and some related packages in jupyter

```
!pip install spacy --user
```

works fine, but

```
!pip install spacy_readability --user
```

results in the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Desktop PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5abs2tnd\\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Desktop PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5abs2tnd\\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-vccpv_5b'
       cwd: C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5abs2tnd\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\
  Complete output (6 lines):
  Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ujson' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Desktop PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5abs2tnd\\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Desktop PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5abs2tnd\\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s9u60ttf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\ujson'
         cwd: C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5abs2tnd\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'ujson' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Desktop PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5abs2tnd\\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Desktop PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5abs2tnd\\ujson_1413fc5067b64d23bce53331a88761c9\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s9u60ttf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Desktop PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\ujson' Check the logs for full command output.
```

any idea how to

Comment: Do you get the same error when you call pip from the command line?

Comment: when i boot up anaconda prompt i get "The system cannot find the drive specified." then it doesn't recognise pip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing `ujson`.

To install `spacy-readability`:

building and creating wheel for `ujson` is needed.

Here is a screenshot from my notebook, when I tried to install `spacy-readability`

[image]

Also, from the error messages it looks like you need `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` or greater if you have an older version.

To install `ujson` try `!pip install ujson`